# Sharepoint. Use CAML query to search items

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I need to search items inside one list. Can i use CAML query? Case need to be ignored and it should find word inside text... Or CAML not for that purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this CAML query:

```
<Where>
  <Contains>
    <FieldRef Name='FilterField' />
    <Value Type='Text'>FilterValue</Value>
  </Contains>
<Where>
```

The contains operator matches items with "FilterValue" in the given field.

Comment: no, it should be case insensitive, but I'm not 100% sure. I have no box around to test it, though.